# Deleting last entry in tableview crashes app with Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ios, swift

First post...

Starting small App with tableview of Aircraft that when I swipe to delete the last entry, App crashes because the row counts don't match.  The entry doesn't delete from Realm either. I am trying to use the trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt since that is the "newer" way to do things and can add more than one action (I also have an Edit action).

If I comment out the `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` all works. I just am trying to put this deleteRows command in to make the animation look better.  With the just the Realm delete, it just snaps the row away (not smoothly). OR is there a better way to do the animation nicely?  Code below...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions:
                                    [makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt: indexPath),
                                     makeEditContextualAction(forRowAt: indexPath)])
    }
    

func makeEditContextualAction(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                    title: "Edit",
                                    handler: { (contextualAction: UIContextualAction, swipeButton: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
                                        print("Hit the EDIT...")
                                            })
    action.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    return action
}

func makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                       title: nil)
                      { (contextualAction: UIContextualAction, swipeButton: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
                        if let aircraftToDelete = self.aircraftResults?[indexPath.row] {
                            do {
                                try self.aircraftRealm.write {
                                    self.aircraftRealm.delete(aircraftToDelete)
                                    //self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)   // Only to make delete look smooth
                                }
                            } catch {
                                print("Error deleting data... \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        self.loadAircraft()
                        completionHandler(true)}
    
    action.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
    action.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    return action
}
```

This then grabs the data from Realm and reloads the table...

```
func loadAircraft() {
        aircraftResults = aircraftRealm.objects(Aircraft.self)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Thanks for the help...
Scott

Answer (score 0):

you will want to delete the aircraft from Realm and then deleteRows(at:, with:) between startUpdating() and stopUpdating(). This won't help if Realm is not deleting your aircraftToDelete.

```
func makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                       title: nil)
                      { (contextualAction: UIContextualAction, swipeButton: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
                        if let aircraftToDelete = self.aircraftResults?[indexPath.row] {
                            do {
                                try self.aircraftRealm.write {
                                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()                                    
                                    self.aircraftRealm.delete(aircraftToDelete)
                                    //self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath]
                                    self.tableView.endUpdates(), 
                                    with: .fade)   // Only to make delete look smooth
                                }
                            } catch {
                                print("Error deleting data... \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        self.loadAircraft()
                        completionHandler(true)}
    
    action.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
    action.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    return action
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  It deletes the aircraft from the Realm just fine without the Begin and Ends.  I tried the following as you suggested but still crashes when deleting the last entry...
                 try self.aircraftRealm.write {
                       self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        self.aircraftRealm.delete(aircraftToDelete)
                         self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)   h
                          self.tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: Would imagine your tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) displays number of rows depending on the count of aircrafts. Your reusable cell is expecting an aircraft most likely. Try returning an empty UITableViewCell() in cellForRowAt if aircraft count is 0 or nil

Comment: `beginUpdates/endUpdates` has no effect at all for a single insert/delete/move operation.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** refetch the data from the database. Instead remove the item from the data source array.

First of all declare the data source array non-optional to get rid of the pointless `if let`

```
var aircraftResults = [Aircraft]()
```

Then **first** delete the item in the database. On success remove the item from the data source array and delete the row.

And call the completion handler passing `false` on error

```
func makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                       title: nil)
                      { (contextualAction: UIContextualAction, swipeButton: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
                        let aircraftToDelete = self.aircraftResults[indexPath.row] {
                        do {
                            try self.aircraftRealm.write {
                                self.aircraftRealm.delete(aircraftToDelete)
                                self.aircraftResults.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)   // Only to make delete look smooth
                                completionHandler(true)
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Error deleting data... \(error)")
                            completionHandler(false)
                        }
                       
    }
    
    action.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
    action.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    return action
}
```

Comment: Hi Vadian...  Its actually a Realm Object and I use the standard Realm Results and use the count on that and not an array.  So there is no such self.aircraftResults.remove(at: indexPath.row) since no array...    The self.aircraftRealm.delete(aircraftToDelete) removes it from the Realm.

Comment: But the line `let aircraftToDelete = self.aircraftResults[indexPath.row]` clearly retrieves the object from an array which is supposed to be the data source array.

Comment: This is how it is defined as a result set of aircraft but not an array. So I use the Realm.delete function much like the array.remove would be...                                    let aircraftRealm = try! Realm()
    var aircraftResults: Results<Aircraft>?         Then reload with         aircraftResults = aircraftRealm.objects(Aircraft.self)

Comment: I appreciate the efforts and am all ears.  Remember that everything deletes OK and refreshes the tableview as long as I comment out the   self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade).  There is no animation though and it looks terrible.  I must be doing something out of sequence or something.  Perhaps it has to do with the Results<Aircraft>? being auto updated constantly.        var aircraftResults: Results<Aircraft>?  *** From docs: Summary

Results is an auto-updating container type in Realm returned from object queries.

Comment: I see. If you want the row animations you have to maintain the data source array yourself. But once again `Results<Aircraft>` **must** be an array otherwise you are not able to get an item by index.

Comment: I agree about equating it to an index.  Its my first time to use Realm as local storage and it seems to be fast and easy to use (except in this instance LOL).  The Realm docs explain better since I'm still reading.  Seems to be a container of elements (objects). Thanks for trying...   Here is the link...  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html